# How can i merge one bean into the other to do a partial update

Tags: java, spring, rest

I want to implement the http-patch method to do a partial update on a resource.

I have a bean that is deserialized with Jackson and contains some valid properties. additionaly i have the a bean that is currently stored in my application.

Is there an easy way to merge the partial bean into the complete bean that does not invole hardcoding the mapping process?

I need to be able to control the process at least in parts (no mapping of the id, no mapping of certain properties).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) with a custom converter ([User guide](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/dozer-user-guide.pdf): page 49) that verifies if the destination is already populated or not.

Dozer has a great [documentation](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/dozer-user-guide.pdf). Can be easily integrated in [spring](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/springintegration.html) / [eclipse](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/eclipse-plugin/usage-editor.html). And you could give it a try

Comment: we decided to use dozer. our beens only use wrapper types (Long) or objects, no primitives. so we can configure dozer to ignore null values and empty strings. this way only real content of the json is copied.

Comment: Great. Glad to hear that it fits your projects.

Answer (score 0):

I have no complete solution but an outline:

I feel that it will be hard to do the merge using Java beans (how will you know which fields have changed?)

So I'd try to get the JSON as a [Jackson Tree Model](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonTreeModel). That way, you can iterate over all the nodes and update the bean yourself.

This will make the merge pretty trivial:

1. Get ID from JSON model
2. Load bean
3. Loop over all JSON nodes, ignoring the immutable ones (id, other dangerous fields)
4. Use Java Bean API to discover properties
5. Use the Spring data conversion helpers to convert the JSON data into Java types.
6. Call the setters yourself
7. Save the modified bean